# Logging emails sent through Outlook to Salesforce

Tags: email, send-email, salesforce-for-outlook

I am trying to find a way log the email that was sent through outlook to a task in salesforce where the address from the To field from the email is matched against an existing contact email from salesforce.

Unfortunately I cannot use the outlook-> salesforce plugin because the related person that is sending the email doesn't have a salesforce license.

I was wondering if there exist an option to set up a unique email address in salesforce and, cc that address to all the emails that are being sent in order to push somehow the information to salesforce. I am unsure if this sort of functionality exists an is easy to implement.

Any ideas, workarounds how to achieve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have implemented this in our CRM,
1) Create a Organization-Wide Email Address
2) When an email is sent to any contact from outlook this address has to be included in BCC
3) Create an email service in Salesforce and perform the logic as per your requirement